# Could not find default endpoint...but it's right there?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

As the title alludes my project keeps telling me it can't find the default endpoint element but it is right there. I mean obviously I must be missing something but I can't figure it out???!!!

Full error msg:
The error message was 'Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'WebChatSvc.ChatServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be....

WebChatSvc is the namespace I chose when I created my web reference.

My app config:

```
...
<appSettings>
<add key="ChatServiceSoap" value="http://localhost:1856/ChatService/ChatService.asmx" />
<add key="LogFilePath" value="" />
<add key="ConString" value="W2K8R2_SQL2K8R2;XXX;YYYY;TTTTT" />
<add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="http://localhost:1856/ChatService/ChatService.asmx" />
</appSettings>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ChatServiceSoap" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1856/ChatService/ChatService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ChatServiceSoap" contract="WebChatSvc.ChatServiceSoap" name="ChatServiceSoap" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>

<applicationSettings>
<ChatClientControl.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="ChatServiceSoap" serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://localhost:1856/ChatService/ChatService.asmx</value>
  </setting>
</ChatClientControl.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I've tried many different variations of the naming possibilities and just can't quite figure it out so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

TIA
JB

Comment: The contract is defined at the service. In WCF, it's usually an interface. What you have is "WebChatSvc.ChatServiceSoap". If WebChatSvc is the namespace you chose in the client, does it exist on the server? Is ChatServiceSoap the name of the contract on the server?

Comment: First this is an older asmx service I inherited so there is no interface that is implemented. WebChatSvc is the namespace I chose when adding the service reference on the client so it is not anywhere on the service. Is ChatServiceSoap the contract name on the server? Now that is where I seem to be getting confused. The service publishes as public class ChatService : System.Web.Services.WebService...but my domain reference is generating a class called ChatServiceSoap? Are settings on my web reference wrong for this older service type?

Comment: From the wsdl of the service: <wsdl:service name="ChatService">
    <wsdl:port name="ChatServiceSoap" binding="tns:ChatServiceSoap"> It looks kinda off to me to have the service name and the port name different?

Comment: With older ASMX web services, I've always just created an instance, then set the URL property.

Comment: When you set up the service reference, did you do it as a web reference? When adding the service reference, click "Advanced" (lower left), then click "Add Web Reference" (lower left button) and add the reference this way. What you have in the web.config is what you would have with a wcf reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You created a service reference. You need to create a web reference.

Delete your currently added service reference. This will remove your endpoint configuration.

In your Solution Explorer, right click on references, then select "Add Service Reference"
Then click "Advanced" (lower left button).
Then click "Add Web Reference" (lower left button)

Then add the service. 
This will put in a different configuration for the web service with the URL.

While you can do it with a service reference, it is a little more work. I think if you just add the asmx web service as a web reference, it will spare you some grief.

Comment: Oh duh!! I knew that but had forgotten. Thank You.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I'd really like to be able to do this. I have some old asmx web services and I really want to add service references to them. Could you please tell me how? I don't mind the extra work :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too. I had an asp.net mvc "Web" project and a "Service" project in my solution. I added my Service Reference to my Service project, which added a `<system.serviceModel>` configuration node to the Service app.config. I fixed it by copying the app.config's `<system.serviceModel>` to my Web project's web.config file.